# Can two relative clauses be used to modify one noun using One Conjunction?

Tags: conjunctions, relative-clauses

1. 

- this is the cycle that I wanted, but my dad didn’t like.
- this is the cycle that I wanted, but my dad didn’t like **it**.

2. 

- She had a pen that the whole class had been looking for and teacher wanted too.
- She had a pen that the whole class had been looking for and teacher wanted **it** too.

3. 

- They provide a value that we all want after seeing.
- They provide a value that we all want after seeing **it**.

which one out of these three pairs is correct?